# Export image to assets only have a part?it looks like be cut

Tags: google-earth-engine

I expect the whole image but only got a part:

[image: expect the whole image but only got a part]

```
imgs=cloudsort(imgs).map(cloudMaskL457).mosaic();
Export.image.toAsset({
    image:imgs.int16().clip(zj),
    description:'clear',
    scale:30,
    maxPixels:1e13
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not specify a **region** parameter in your Export.image.toAsset function. If the region is not specified, the Export task takes the current map view as the export region. The image was most likely "cut" to that extent